# get_field do not giving output in advance custom field

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

This is my code but this is not giving any input

```
    <?php
        if(get_field('header'))
        {
    ?>
    <div class="about-us">
        <div class="--header">  
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/assets/images/laptop.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">

                <?php echo '<h2>' . the_field('heading') . '</h2>';
                echo '<h4>' . get_field('description') . '</h4>';?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }

    ?>
```

[This is my custom filed that i created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9LmE.png)

Comment: did you used it in a loop? or in a single page?

Comment: @AliQorbani single page

Comment: did you changed **line:9** `the_field` to `get_field` ?

Answer (score 0):

`the_field` function **echo**s value. so you don't have to use it in another echo function

please try this code and let me know if it works.

```
<?php
if ( get_field('header') ){
    ?>
    <div class="about-us">
        <div class="--header">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/assets/images/laptop.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">

                <?php echo '<h2>' . get_field('heading') . '</h2>';
                echo '<h4>' . get_field('description') . '</h4>'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}else{
    _e('the field header not founded','textdomain');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still not getting value from ACF, then you should get value like  as  below:

```
<?php
  $post_id = false; // current post
  $post_id = 1; // post ID = 1
  $post_id = "user_2"; // user ID = 2
  $post_id = "category_3"; // category term ID = 3
  $post_id = "event_4"; // event (custom taxonomy) term ID = 4
  $post_id = "option"; // options page
  $post_id = "options"; // same as above

  echo $value = get_field( 'my_field', $post_id );
?>
```

I hope it would help you out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have written a wrong condition. There is no field for `header` it is just a group where you have created all custom fields. You can give a condition on the custom fields.

So, you need to write a condition like this.

```
<?php
    if( get_field( 'heading' ) ) {
        // Your Code
    }
?>
```